# How do I add tracking number to current order shipment in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, shipping, dependency-injection, shipment-tracking

I did find sample codes for Magento 1.x. But I have no idea how to do this on Magento 2.

Can anyone describe how to implement this using **Dependency Injection (DI)**?

Thanks.

```
$trackingDetail = array(
    'carrier_code' => 'ups',
    'title' => 'United Parcel Service',
    'number' => 'TORD23254WERZXd3', // Replace with your tracking number
);

$track = Mage::getModel('sales/order_shipment_track')->addData($trackingDetail);
$shipment->addTrack($track);


$transactionSave = Mage::getModel('core/resource_transaction')
->addObject($shipment)
->addObject($shipment->getOrder())
->save();
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

AFAIK the track object is the same in M2.

However, the rest of the code has changed.

```
$data = array(
    'carrier_code' => 'ups',
    'title' => 'United Parcel Service',
    'number' => 'TORD23254WERZXd3', // Replace with your tracking number
);

$track = $this->trackFactory->create()->addData($data);
$shipment->addTrack($track)->save();
```

Where `$this->trackFactory` an instance of `Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Shipment\TrackFactory` and `$shipment` is your shipment object.

Comment: BTW I wonder if you know how to get order shipment comments too for MG2.  If you do please post it here. Thanks.

Comment: How to add tracking URl in shipment?

Comment: @Roshanruzaik, if you are asking how to add comment to the shipment then this is how i have done:$commentText = 'Test comment';
//Comment interface : \Magento\Sales\Api\Data\ShipmentCommentCreationInterface 
$comment= $this->commentInterface->setComment($commentText);
//use $comment as one of the paramter while creating shipment as below example:

//ship order service: \Magento\Sales\Model\ShipOrder
$this->shipOrderService->execute($orderId,$shippedItems,$notify,$includeComment,$comment,$tracks);

Comment: Hi @Raphael at digital pianism sipping tracking number, and carrier_code is saving in "sales_shipment_track" table in magento2 but where it will save the Shipping Charge ?

Comment: can you please help on this similar question https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/268844/adding-tracking-number-to-existing-orders-from-csv-file-programmatically-in-mage

Comment: how to get the shipment object here

Answer (score 12):

Adding to the accepted answer, it would be a good idea to use repositories instead of the deprecated save method. Also added the customer notification after the tracking creation.

```
/** @var Magento\Sales\Model\Order\ShipmentRepository */
protected $_shipmentRepository;

/** @var Magento\Shipping\Model\ShipmentNotifier */
protected $_shipmentNotifier;

/** @var Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Shipment\TrackFactory */
protected $_trackFactory; //missing ;

public function __construct(
  \Magento\Shipping\Model\ShipmentNotifier $shipmentNotifier, 
  \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\ShipmentRepository $shipmentRepository, 
  \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Shipment\TrackFactory $trackFactory)
{
  $this->_shipmentNotifier = $shipmentNotifier;
  $this->_shipmentRepository = $shipmentRepository;
  $this->_trackFactory = $trackFactory;
}
public function addTrack($shipment, $carrierCode, $description, $trackingNumber) 
{
    /** Creating Tracking */
    /** @var Track $track */
    $track = $this->_trackFactory->create();
    $track->setCarrierCode($carrierCode);
    $track->setDescription($description);
    $track->setTrackNumber($trackingNumber);
    $shipment->addTrack($track);
    $this->_shipmentRepository->save($shipment);

    /* Notify the customer*/
    $this->_shipmentNotifier->notify($shipment);
 }
```

Where $shipment is your shipment object. Notify will notify (send email) to the user and add a history item to the order status history collection.

Comment: It did not work for me have created helper class , i am able to fetch getDeiveryTime(), getCancelTime(),getDispatchTime() but i am unable to get tracking number. Can you provide a list of functions to fetch rest details of the shipment

Comment: can you help on this similar question? https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/268844/adding-tracking-number-to-existing-orders-from-csv-file-programmatically-in-mage

Comment: @carol Castro, how can we add the order id here?

Answer (score 0):

In Magento 2.4.5-p1: By using the below code we can save tracking information in order shipment.

```
<?php
namespace Module\ImportTrackingNumber\Model\Shipment;

use Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderInterface;

class Track
{
    /**
     *
     * @var \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;;
     */
    protected $logger;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Sales\Model\Spi\OrderResourceInterface
     */
    protected $orderResource;

    /**
     * @var Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderInterfaceFactory
     */
    protected $orderInterfaceFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Sales\Api\Data\ShipmentTrackInterfaceFactory
     */
    protected $shipmentTrackInterfaceFactory;
           
    /**
     *
     * @var \Magento\Sales\Api\ShipmentTrackRepositoryInterface;
     */
    protected $shipmentTrackRepository;
    
   /**
    *
    * @param \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger
    * @param \Magento\Sales\Model\Spi\OrderResourceInterface $orderResource
    * @param \Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderInterfaceFactory $orderInterfaceFactory
    * @param \Magento\Sales\Api\Data\ShipmentTrackInterfaceFactory $shipmentTrackInterfaceFactory
    * @param \Magento\Sales\Api\ShipmentTrackRepositoryInterface $shipmentTrackRepository
    */
    public function __construct(
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
        \Magento\Sales\Model\Spi\OrderResourceInterface $orderResource,
        \Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderInterfaceFactory $orderInterfaceFactory,
        \Magento\Sales\Api\Data\ShipmentTrackInterfaceFactory $shipmentTrackInterfaceFactory,
        \Magento\Sales\Api\ShipmentTrackRepositoryInterface $shipmentTrackRepository
    ) {
        $this->logger = $logger;
        $this->orderResource = $orderResource;
        $this->orderInterfaceFactory = $orderInterfaceFactory;
        $this->shipmentTrackInterfaceFactory = $shipmentTrackInterfaceFactory;
        $this->shipmentTrackRepository = $shipmentTrackRepository;
    }

    /**
     * save the order tracking information
     *
     * @param array $data
     * @return bool
     */
    public function saveTrackingData($data)
    { 
        try {
            $incrementId = $data['increment_id'] ?: '';
            $trackingNumber = $data['tracking_number'] ?: '';
            $carrierCode = $data['carrier_code'] ?: '';
               
            $order = $this->orderInterfaceFactory->create();
            $this->orderResource->load($order, $incrementId, OrderInterface::INCREMENT_ID);

            $shipmentId = $this->getOrderShipmentId($order);

            if ($shipmentId) {
                $shipmentTrack = $this->shipmentTrackInterfaceFactory->create();

                $shipmentTrack->setParentId($shipmentId);
                $shipmentTrack->setOrderId($order->getId());
                $shipmentTrack->setCarrierCode($carrierCode);
                $shipmentTrack->setTrackNumber($trackingNumber);

                $this->shipmentTrackRepository->save($shipmentTrack);
            } 
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->logger->error($e->getMessage());
        }

        return false;
    }

    /**
     * save the order tracking information
     *
     * @param \Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderInterface $order
     * @return int $shipmentId
     */
    public function getOrderShipmentId($order)
    {
        $shipmentId = 0;

        if ($order->hasShipments()) {

            $shipmentCollection = $order->getShipmentsCollection();

            foreach ($shipmentCollection as $shipment) {
                $shipmentId = $shipment->getId();
            }
        }

        return $shipmentId;
    }
}
```