# How can we add Tracking number using third party API in order when shipment create in Magento 2.3.5?

Tags: magento2, shipment-tracking, magento2.3.5-p1

I want to add a Tracking number using third party API when creating shipment from admin.
Also, how can we override that observer?
I am using Magento 2.3.5.
I have referred one link but it is for Magento 1.9. ([How do I add tracking number to current order shipment in Magento 2?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/156223/how-do-i-add-tracking-number-to-current-order-shipment-in-magento-2))

Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the REST API provided by Magento.

**In this case use this webservice http://yoursite.com/index.php/rest/V1/shipment/track**

```
{
  "entity": {
    "order_id":     your order id,
    "parent_id":    your shipment id,
    "track_number": "track number",
    "tittle": "carrier tittle",
    "carrier_code": "carrier code"
  }
}
```

Include in the header the following information:
Content-Type application/json
Authorization Bearer your_auth_token

Any help needed feel free to ask !

Comment: Where can i get the parent_id of a order??